# Inverse of COALESCE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

is there a function in SQL Server 2005 that returns NULL [or a boolean value] if **any** of the arguments (of any type) is NULL, which would save me from writing `IF a IS NULL OR b IS NULL OR c IS NULL ...`.

Comment: @Michael B: Likely the last item in the list since it's not null and will suffice. The focus is NULL so although a non-NULL value is important, the actual value is irrelevant.

Comment: Also NULL, because *any* implies *none*.

Comment: @ecran: (Assuming your comment is a response to @Michael B), Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of the function you want, if you return null when no null is present? I mean the function would always return null.

Comment: The real question might be: What is returned if the list is empty?

Comment: @jdk: Actually, it was a mistake that I said NULL must be returned. A boolean return value would suffice (like OR returns). 1 for no NULLs in parameter-list and 0 if any NULLs, or vice versa...

Comment: I'm curious, is this a task that is really for SQL? This sounds like business logic more than data management. Why not just pass the resultset to your app and let the app make the quick-parse determination? Or is my backwards brain not grasping something this AM pre caffeine?

Comment: You are right, the question comes out of curiosity. I came up with it as I wrote a query for an ad-hoc report out of datawarehouse, so there is no "app". But I don't think that DBMSs should strictly stick with ANSI SQL and omit such helper functions. In the end, what COALESCE does can be achieved in app level too, but think how often we use COALESCE in queries...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a moderately unpleasant way of doing it:

```
set ansi_nulls off
if (null in (a, b, c, d, e) print 'got a null'
set ansi_nulls on
```

Comment: ~shudders at the implications~

Comment: A stern caution from Microsoft that NULL can produce unexpected results in this scenario: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Since NULLs propogate you could do:

```
(cola + colb + colc) is null
```

assuming all compatible data types

Comment: That's why I put the constraint **of any type** in the post ;)

Comment: Maybe you could coerce them into a single type, since the values themselves don't matter for the test. Maybe a nullable bit?

Answer (score 1):

No, the closest you an get is NULLIF(), but that's not what you want.  I'd just stick to using the OR statement here.

Comment: Actually, NULLIF returns NULL if the two input-parameters are the same. I don't see any way to achieve this with cascaded NULLIFs.

Answer (score 0):

How about ...

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN NULLIF(ISNULL(@testA, 1), @testA) 
        + NULLIF(ISNULL(@testB, 1), @testB) 
        + NULLIF(ISNULL(@testC, 1), @testC) > 0
    THEN 'Got NULL'
    ELSE 'NO NULL'
END
```

Comment: This takes care of the **"of any type"** constraint, but for the sake of readability, I would prefer `@testA IS NULL OR @testB IS NULL OR @testC IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of SQL Server, but in similar database (I used hive here which is more close to traditional DBMS in terms of syntax) `select isnull(concat(*)) from some_table;` would help to check if any of the column is `NULL`.

Hope there is some way to play around this concept in SQL Server and my suggestion helps to solve the problem efficiently.